# MySql conditional

Tags: mysql, select, if-statement

I can't quite get this query to work how I want it to.

```
IF(h.STATUS="On-Login-Screen") OR (h.STATUS="IE-Window-Missing") 
SELECT MAX(h.TIME) limit 1 AS LastDown
```

Essentially I want to check the last time h.Status equaled one of the above things, and get the most recent time when it does equal one of those things as a variable named LastDown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT MAX(h.TIME) AS LastDown
FROM TABLENAME
WHERE (h.STATUS='On-Login-Screen') OR (h.STATUS='IE-Window-Missing') 
--limit 1
```

Or

```
SELECT MAX(h.TIME) AS LastDown
FROM TABLENAME
WHERE h.STATUS IN ('On-Login-Screen','IE-Window-Missing')
```

Comment: The second example is better, as it will use an index, if found.

Comment: Is there a way to do this for each ID?

Comment: @Damien.Bell what do you meant by each ID? can you post example?